# How can we stop being logged straight back out on login with Win XP?

Tags: windows-xp, login, windows-media-center

We are having problems with laptop running Win XP Media Centre edition.

On boot up the Welcome screen is shown. When we enter the password to login it appears to be accepted but we are immediatly logged out back to the welcome screen.

We have tried booting into safe mode with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really the right place to ask, but I'll answer anyway...

This is normally because the userinit.exe file is damaged, from system32. Replace it with a good version, or use a repair disk. This is normally caused by the file being infected by a virus - because it runs on login, which is good -  and then deleted by an AV.

Comment: +1 Most of the times, it means that you're system might have some malware trouble. A successful login and then an immediate logoff means that the user's session wasn't setup properly.